# can't change the size of all fonts CSS WP

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, web-deployment

At first I noticed the font sizes are large on the site and uncomfortable inside each article
I tried customizing the CSS file
To write a code that makes fonts smaller
for paragraphs and sub-headings
H2، H3
I tried some articles and found that the fonts have really changed and become smaller
But the problem is not all the fonts in some articles, the problem remains the fonts are in large sizes and have not changed
What is the cause of the problem and how can I set all the fonts in all articles smaller than the original size
See the picture that shows you a check mark
This has the fonts changed successfully, while the other picture has the font not changed
Then see also the code and a picture of where the code was modified

[image: Font changed]

[image: The font has not changed]

[image: code modification file]

```
body {
font-size: 16px !important;
line-height: 35px !important;
}
.default_logo,.logo-sticky,.logo-mobile{
height: 110px !important;
}
.fullwidth-wrapper {
padding: 15px 30px;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 1200px){
.wgl-theme-header .wgl-mobile-header {
display: block;
height: 120px;
}
.default_logo, .logo-sticky, .logo-mobile {
margin-top: 10px;
}

h2 {
font-size:24px !important;
}
h3 {
font-size:20px !important;
}
h4 {
font-size:18px !important;
}
}
```

Can't change the size of all fonts in wp

Comment: I tend to code manually so not that familiar with Wordpress but can you edit the `p` tags to change the font size as you have done with the `h` tags?

Comment: Maybe you have some inline styles?

Comment: I think you need to clear the cache of your site and browser.